# Combination Problem Involving Integers 1-9 to Reach a Sum of 10

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I received a word problem that goes like this.

A local kindergarten is thinking of making posters that show all the different ways of adding two or more integers from 1 to 9 to get a sum of 10. If there is enough space on each poster for up to 50 possible solutions, how many posters will the school need to make?

(Note: sums that contain the same number but in a different order are considered to be different; for example, 1 + 9 and 9 + 1 are two different solutions.)

What is the answer to this problem, and more importantly, how do I solve it?

To be clear, a solution such as,"1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1+1," is a valid one.

Please make your explanation somewhat thorough and be available to explain further. Thanks!

Comment: You already posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912409/amount-of-number-combinations-to-reach-a-sum-of-10-with-integers-1-9-using-2-or).  Please do not post [duplicate questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates).

Answer (score 2):

Since the summands must be at least $1$ and at most $9$, a particular solution to the question corresponds to the placement of one or more addition signs in the nine spaces between successive ones in a row of ten ones.
$$1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1 \square 1$$
For instance, 
$$1 + 1 1 + 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $1 + 2 + 3 + 4$.  The number of such solutions is equal to the number of non-empty subsets of a nine-element set, which is $2^9 - 1$.

To see this, observe that we have two choices for each of the nine spaces, to place an addition sign or not place one.  That gives us $2^9$ solutions.  However, we cannot leave all the spaces empty since that would correspond to using the summand $10$, which is not permitted.  Therefore, the number of admissible solutions is $2^9 - 1$.

This sort of problem is called a [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)).

I will leave it to you to determine how many posters will be needed.

Answer (score 0):

There are fourty two partitions of 10.  You *could* simply list them all, then count how many distinct permuatations each has.

10 has $1$

9 + 1 has $2$

8 + 2 has $2$

8 + 1 + 1 has $3$

7 + 3 has $2$

7 + 2 + 1 has $6$

7 + 1 + 1 + 1 has $4$

et cetera

2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 2 has $1$

2 + 2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 has $\binom 64$

2 + 2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 has $\binom 73$

2 + 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 has $\binom 82$

2 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 has $9$

1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 has $1$

> But if you think about it a bit more, there is a cleaver solution.